# set number of digits after decimal point in vtkRectilinearGridWriter

Tags: vtk, scientific-computing

I use vtk library and vtkRectilinearGridWriter to write output vtk files in my scientific research. But the precision is low. So my question is:

How to specify number of digits after decimal point while writing data by vtkRectilinearGridWriter class? It seems that there is not explicit setter method for that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

the class VtkRectilinearGridWriter inherits from vtkAlgorithm that has an enumeration for set the desire output precision `enum vtkAlgorithm::DesiredOutputPrecision` you can set it to SINGLE_PRECISION or DOUBLE_PRECISION. See more about vtkAlgorithm [here](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkAlgorithm.html#ac2bf3c779aa60908da5bc3df9b066db6)

Comment: How can I set the DesiredOutputPrecision? Say I have `vtkSmartPointer<vtkTriangleFilter> triangles = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTriangleFilter>::New();` This does not work. `triangles->DesiredOutputPrecision = vtkTriangleFilter::DOUBLE_PRECISION;` :(